# XSL - Whitespace issue when setting dynamically placeholder

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xslt template, in which i am loading translation content from xml files.

I want to set dynamically the placeholder in an input field, but apparently I am keep getting whitespace (the placeholder is moved to the right).

[image]

Here is my code.

```
<xsl:attribute name="placeholder">
 <xsl:value-of select="/paygate/language/computop.creditcard.number.message"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

I tried removing the whitespace between the lines, also setting

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

in the beginning of the file. Nothing worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT processor ought to strip whitespace-only text nodes that are direct children of an `<xsl:attribute>` by default.  If the transform you present is producing `placeholder` attributes with unwanted leading or trailing whitespace in their values, then, I conclude it is coming from the application of the `<xsl:value-of>` element; its result is not subject to whitespace stripping.

In that case, you could consider applying the standard `normalize-space()` XPath function to the attribute value:

```
<xsl:attribute name="placeholder">
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string(/paygate/language/computop.creditcard.number.message))"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

`normalize-space()` will delete both leading and trailing whitespace from its (string) argument, but will also replace each internal run of whitespace characters with a single space character.